# Python+OpenCV: cv2.imwrite

Tags: python, opencv, python-2.7, numpy

I'm trying to detect a face and write down area with the face in a separate file.
How can I do it? I think that i must use "faces" (you can see this var in code). But how?

```
from ffnet import mlgraph, ffnet, tmlgraph, imlgraph
import pylab
import sys
import cv,cv2
import numpy
cascade = cv.Load('C:\opencv\data\haarcascades\haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml')


def detect(image):
 bitmap = cv.fromarray(image)
 faces = cv.HaarDetectObjects(bitmap, cascade, cv.CreateMemStorage(0))
 if faces:
  for (x,y,w,h),n in faces:  
   cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,255,255),3)
 return image

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    while 1:
        _,frame =cam.read()
        frame = numpy.asarray(detect(frame))
        cv2.imshow("features", frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == 0x1b: # ESC
            print 'ESC pressed. Exiting ...'
            break
```

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This following code should extract face in images and save faces on disk

```
def detect(image):
    image_faces = []
    bitmap = cv.fromarray(image)
    faces = cv.HaarDetectObjects(bitmap, cascade, cv.CreateMemStorage(0))
    if faces:
        for (x,y,w,h),n in faces:
            image_faces.append(image[y:(y+h), x:(x+w)])
            #cv2.rectangle(image,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,255,255),3)
    return image_faces

if __name__ == "__main__":
    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    while 1:
        _,frame =cam.read()
        image_faces = []
        image_faces = detect(frame)
        for i, face in enumerate(image_faces):
            cv2.imwrite("face-" + str(i) + ".jpg", face)

        #cv2.imshow("features", frame)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) == 0x1b: # ESC
            print 'ESC pressed. Exiting ...'
            break
```

Answer (score 6):

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Alternatively**, with [MTCNN](https://github.com/kpzhang93/MTCNN_face_detection_alignment) and OpenCV(other dependencies including TensorFlow also required), you can:

1 **Perform face detection**(Input an image, output all boxes of detected faces):

```
from mtcnn.mtcnn import MTCNN
import cv2

face_detector = MTCNN()

img = cv2.imread("Anthony_Hopkins_0001.jpg")
detect_boxes = face_detector.detect_faces(img)
print(detect_boxes)
```

> [{'box': [73, 69, 98, 123], 'confidence': 0.9996458292007446, 'keypoints': {'left_eye': (102, 116), 'right_eye': (150, 114), 'nose': (129, 142), 'mouth_left': (112, 168), 'mouth_right': (146, 167)}}]

2 **save all detected faces to separate files**:

```
for i in range(len(detect_boxes)):
    box = detect_boxes[i]["box"]
    face_img = img[box[1]:(box[1] + box[3]), box[0]:(box[0] + box[2])]
    cv2.imwrite("face-{:03d}.jpg".format(i+1), face_img)
```

3 or **Draw rectangles** of all detected faces:

```
for box in detect_boxes:
    box = box["box"]
    pt1 = (box[0], box[1]) # top left
    pt2 = (box[0] + box[2], box[1] + box[3]) # bottom right
    cv2.rectangle(img, pt1, pt2, (0,255,0), 2)
cv2.imwrite("detected-boxes.jpg", img)
```

Comment: for a large number of faces, what I am doing right now is saving all the faces and bounding boxes to lists and then saving these lists of numpy arrays to disk using h5py.  Is there a better way?

Comment: @mLstudent33 I didn't quite get that. You may ask a question on SOF, with more detailed information, e.g. input, output, and what you are doing to accomplish that. Then see anyone could help.

Answer (score 1):

wtluo, great !
May I propose a slight modification of your code 2. ? Here it is:

```
for i, detected_box in enumerate(detect_boxes):
    box = detected_box["box"]
    face_img = img[ box[1]:box[1] + box[3], box[0]:box[0] + box[2] ]
    cv2.imwrite("face-{:03d}.jpg".format(i+1), face_img)
```

Comment: Can you share why your modification is better, or in what cases it would be better?

Comment: gar, this modification is a less verbose version of the same code. As such, it might be shorter to read, easier to understand and quicker to process.
About the imwrite line (as I can now understand that this was your topic), hasn't it been recommended for a while now to use function `format()` rather than operator `%` on strings?

Comment: @Schmouk thanks for your advice! And my name is `xtluo` not `wtluo`. ^_^