# Face recognition. OpenCV+Python+ffnet

Tags: opencv, python-2.7

I'm Alexander Mashkovtsev, student of gymnasium "Akademy", Kyiv, Ukrane. I'm 15.
I'd like to do face recognition program using OpenCV.
I write science work about face recognition, too.

It's very interesting for me, so i search a command.
I'd like to demonstrate the work on Kyiv High-Technology Center to get help with this.

There are people who are ready help me to create this program?
I will be grateful. Also ready to to reward the person who will help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

have a look [at the opencv facereco docs](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/contrib/doc/facerec/index.html)

or, [here](https://github.com/berak/opencv_smallfry/blob/master/facerec_online.py) for a small python demo (yea, i 've seen your other questions here, that's why i'm posting the latter).

---

but ofc, you want to write your own, if i understood that right, that's great!

Comment: Yes, I want write my own.

Comment: About https://github.com/berak/opencv_smallfry/blob/master/facerec_online.py
How to show to the program path of the images and haar?

Comment: How to show the path ? maybe i don't understand you. every person gets a folder relative to where you start the script. and the haarcascades should be in the opencv/data/haarcascades folder, like in your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20425724/pythonopencv-cv2-imwrite)

Comment: When i running the program - this message in console: 
USAGE: facerec_online.py </path/to/images> <path/to/cascadefile>

What i might do? I didn't find answer in the code.

Sorry for my English:) I'm Ukrainian.

Comment: oohh, now i get it ;)  -  you're supposed to give args on the cmdline, start it like: facerec_online.py "." "C:/opencv/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml"

Comment: ook. I tried to do this. 
Console:

>>>  facerec_online.py "img" "C:/opencv/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml"
 
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1
    facerec_online.py "img" "C:/opencv/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml"
   ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>> facerec_online.py "img"
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>>  facerec_online.py "." "C:/opencv/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml"
 
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1
    facerec_online.py "." "C:/opencv/data/haarcascades/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml"
   ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
>>>

Comment: shame on me, but i got no idea about pyshell. can you try a 'normal' console ?

Comment: I started through the winCMD. The console opened, i saw that program suggested to input keys (esc, a, or t), then another message printed and program closed

Comment: ok, call it progress ;) next it's looking for the webcam, after that tries to load the cascade file. if everything works fine, it will open a window. if you see a box around the face, you can press 'a' to save a person's face..

Comment: It doesn't work fine, i see. 
It opens console window, prints that i wrote before this and momently close the window

Comment: i'm a bit out of ideas ;( maybe don't waste too much time there, and concentrate on your own ?

Comment: I just want to see the example. It's interesting :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Face++ SDKs are more easier than OpenCV.

You can refer to [Face++](http://www.faceplusplus.com/) website, look through their API docs overview.

Good luck!